# Can't install Ubuntu, the 'Install' home screen is a white box

Tags: system-installation

I have a curious issue. When I burn the ISO and reboot, I'm greeted with the Ubuntu splash screen, then it loads into the Welcome menu. I cannot do anything at this point, can't interact with it, move the menu, etc.

the menu itself is just a giant white box, so I don't know the contents or a way to move past that screen.

Any ideas? this is 12.04, tried both 32 and 64 bit.

Typing this out, I'm going to remove any USB devices and try again.

Comment: Have you [MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) the ISO?

Comment: Yep - they checked out the same.

Comment: Can you see the menu by using the USB/CD on another computer?

Answer (score 1):

Try the alternative installer [HERE](http://mirrors.melbourne.co.uk/ubuntu-releases/precise/).  This works for me for whenever I have a really old computer that will not run the regular installer.

Comment: Since this mirror is taking long to load alternatively use [this](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/).